# Create event recursively in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I would like to create click event on every window. (parent and iframes);
Here's my **code:**

```
function createClicks(e) {
    if(!e) e = $(document);
    iframe = e.find('iframe');
    if(iframe.length) createClicks(iframe.contents())
    e.click(dosomething); //create click event
}
```

when I fire the function `createClicks()`, it only creates click event for `$(document)` but not for `iframe`.

Any idea?

Comment: Is the iframe in the same domain as the main page? If it's in a different domain you can't do anything to it.

Comment: I would **highly** recommend not making a variable named `e` point to something that is not an event.  This has a high chance of causing confusion for other programmers.

Comment: Yes Same domain

Comment: @Taplar thanks for the note

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found why iframe click events not created.
it was because I called the createClicks on the load of parent window however the iframes not yet loaded therefore the events for iframes can't be created.

what I did is I setTimout for createClicks function then it works.

```
setTimeout(createClicks,1000);
```

most probably there's better solution. but this what works for me.